# Making a Java class more flexible

Tags: java, oop, jdbc, interface, abstract-class

Upto now, whenever I am dealing with the database, I used to create one Interface called `DatabaseConnector` and one class which implements it called `DatabaseHandler`. Below is an example of `DatabaseConnector` (with parameters removed)

```
public interface DBConnectorIntf 
{    
    //Conection stuff
    public void createConnection();
    public void closeConnection();
    public void checkConnection();

    public void insertUser(------);
    public void insertSubUser(----);
    public void updateUser(-----);
    public void updateSubUser(------);
    public void updateSubUserType(------);
    public void deleteUser(-----);   
    public void deleteSubUser(-----);   
    public void deleteSubUserType(------); 
}
```

However we have around 30 tables (which means around 90 methods) so if we add every single insert, delete and update method (which means around 90 methods) of those tables into this `interface` and implement it using `DatabaseHandler`, then there will be below issues.

1. Only one person can develop that class, everyone else has to wait until he is done.
2. If someone need a change in at least one method, then he has to call the developer of the class.
3. There will be approximately 20,000 line codes.
4. This is going to be a one man show, so it will cost time.

Due to these reasons, what we need to do is "break" this into small pieces and give it to 4,5 people to develop. How can we do this?

There is a proposed method, where we create one class per one database table. So there will be classes like `UserTable`, `SubUserTable`, SubUserTypeTable` etc.

Below is an example.

```
public abstract class DBMaster()
{
   public void createConnection(){CODE HERE};
   public void closeConnection(){CODE HERE};
   public void checkConnection(){CODE HERE};
}

public class UserTable extends DBMaster
{
   public void insertUser(------){CODE};
   public void deletetUser(------){CODE};
   public void updateUser(------){CODE};
}

public class SubUserTable extends DBMaster
{
   public void insertSubUser(------){CODE};
   public void deleteSubUser(------){CODE};
   public void updateSubUser(------){CODE};
}
```

So which method is much more standard? Or any other way like this? (No `Hibernate` etc)

**Update**

I know there are frameworks like `Hibernate` etc etc. But that is not the question here but to know which of the above way is standard, therefor please provide me answers/comments to the questioned problem.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to reinvent ORM and DAO.

Comment: use hibernate, spring jdbc, or some activerecord implementation. but don't roll your own, it's a waste of time.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? As suggested, use Hibernate for your database CRUD uses

Comment: You should have an interface for `User` (or better `UserService`), not for `DBMaster`. `DBMaster` wants a connection pool or factory pattern. In this way a developer who wants to use the `User` class only needs to develop the interface. The DB developer then implements it. Like everyone said use an existing framework like Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Most standard way for dealing with this is using JPA, that is part of Java EE.
Probably its most famous implementation is Hibernate, so I recommend you to use JPA/Hibernate.

You can find a lot of information about this on google, for example: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html